# How can I make git do the "did you mean" suggestion?

Tags: git

I type

```
git puhs
```

And git says:

```
kristian@office:~/myrepo$ git puhs
git: 'puhs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Did you mean this?
      push
```

What is the config setting to make git just do the suggested command if it only has one suggestion ?

Comment: `git config --global help.autocorrect prompt`  will actually prompt and ask for confirmation before applying the fix, starting git 2.34 (Q4 2021). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329756/6309).

Answer (score 152, accepted):

According to [git-config(1)](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html), you want to set `help.autocorrect` appropriately.  For example, `git config --global help.autocorrect 5` will make it wait half a second before running the command so you can see the message first.

Comment: If you set it to a negative number, it does it directly.

Comment: Is there a way to make git prompt before correcting, similar to zsh? (e.g., "correct 'puhs' to 'push' [yn]?")

Comment: @AchalDave There probably is, if you write the code to do that and submit the patch/branch to the `git` folks to have it accepted into the code base. Currently, it doesn't work that way...

Comment: This seems to work iff there's exactly one candidate command. For example, `git stat` does nothing even after using your suggestion because it has multiple candidates. Any suggestion on how to make it choose the first one?

Answer (score 26):

The autocorrect is nice, but my OCD-self needs a little more control over what's going on. So, I wrote a straightforward script that just chooses the first suggestion provided by git. You run the script after the failed command and use the built in bash history substitution "bang bang" syntax. Also, if you are typing something that could possibly have more than one command, this command lets you choose one other than the first option.

It would look something like this,

```
kristian@office:~/myrepo$ git puhs
git: 'puhs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Did you mean this?
      push

kristian@office:~/myrepo$ idid !!
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.17 KiB, done.
Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Plus, it's fun to type anything with two exclamation points. So bonus for that.

Here's a [gist with my script](https://gist.github.com/papaben/463d72bb4ea329754566fa82ef0c949e)

Comment: To be honest though, typing `git push` is faster than typing `idid !!`. But in other cases this script would be useful :)

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative to help.autocorrect: if you make the same typos all the time, you can create aliases for them in your .gitconfig file

```
[alias]
    puhs = push
```

(I do this with shell aliases too, where I can never seem to type `mkae^H^H^H^Hmake` correctly.)

Answer (score 18):

Also take a look at [`thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck)

It can correct typos, and also perform suggestions. Not just limited to git.

Comment: I have been using `fuck` command for 2 years now, it has become one of my "cannot live without it" terminal modifications!!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to make git *prompt* before correcting, similar to zsh?
> (e.g., "`correct 'puhs' to 'push' [yn]?`")

That was asked in 2015. 6 years later:

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the logic for auto-correction of misspelt subcommands learned to go **interactive** when the **`help.autocorrect`** configuration variable is set to '**`prompt`**'.

See [commit dc66e3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc66e3c799cd5d8f3e664e26899bca200ffdfd7b) (14 Aug 2021) by [Azeem Bande-Ali (`azeemba`)](https://github.com/azeemba).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 96ac07f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96ac07f4a93ae9c2012c7b13aa204d39e8cba6e1), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`help.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc66e3c799cd5d8f3e664e26899bca200ffdfd7b): `help.autocorrect=prompt` waits for user action
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Azeem Bande-Ali</sup>

> If `help.autocorrect` is set to '`prompt`', the user is prompted before the suggested action is executed.
>
> Based on [original patch by **David Barr**](https://lore.kernel.org/git/1283758030-13345-1-git-send-email-david.barr@cordelta.com/) (from... Sept. 2010!).

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dc66e3c799cd5d8f3e664e26899bca200ffdfd7b/Documentation/config/help.txt#L12-L20):

> git will try to suggest the correct command or even
> run the suggestion automatically.
>
> Possible config values are:
>
> - `0` (default): show the suggested command.
> - `positive number`: run the suggested command after specified
>   deciseconds (0.1 sec).
> - "`immediate`": run the suggested command immediately.
> - "`prompt`": show the suggestion and prompt for confirmation to run
>   the command.
> - "`never`": don't run or show any suggested command.

---

Note that, with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), when proposing to run a command, the prompt has been updated to match what the others similar questions create.

It is no longer:

```
Run '%s' instead? (y/N)
```

But:

```
Run '%s' instead [y/N]?
```

See [commit 0fc8ed1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fc8ed154cd9f110e8234cd54aa9324182978d26) (15 Dec 2021) by [Kashav Madan (`kashav`)](https://github.com/kashav).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a165484](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a16548404789771fd3ee69f301893a08ef268bb2), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`help`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fc8ed154cd9f110e8234cd54aa9324182978d26): make auto-correction prompt more consistent
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kashav Madan</sup>

> There are three callsites of `git_prompt()` helper function that ask a "yes/no" question to the end user, but one of them in [`help.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0fc8ed154cd9f110e8234cd54aa9324182978d26/help.c) that asks if the suggested auto-correction is OK, which is given when the user makes a possible typo in a Git subcommand name, is formatted differently from the others.
>
> Update the format string to make the prompt string look more consistent.

Comment: Is there still no way to have it let you select among the suggested commands if there are multiple?

Comment: @LSpice Not that I know of. I do not see any other recent evolution on `help.c`.