# Bash - show suggestions

Tags: bash

using Git, when I type something like this:

```
$ git statsu
```

I get...

```
git: 'statsu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    status
```

How can I replicate this using Bash?

---

I could, of course, do this by making a huge `case` of all possible transposed letters... but that would take forever, and seems really dirty...

```
case $1 in
  "statsu")
    suggestion="status"
  ;;
  "satsus")
    suggestion="status"
  ;;
  ...
esac
```

**How can I replicate this behavior in my own program?**

*(related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167367/how-can-i-make-git-do-the-did-you-mean-suggestion), but that is talking about configuring git ITSELF to print this message)*

Comment: You want to do this for what? Top-level commands? Subcommands of arbitrary programs? Subcommands of a specific program written in bash? Something else?

Comment: In general, doing this _well_ is going to call for a lexicographic distance algorithm, and that's not an easy thing to implement in native bash.

Comment: He wants to program a script so that programmtically if you type something incorrect in git it will follow the instructions?

Comment: a sub-command of a program I design. yea.  `myprogram tpoy`. "did you mean `myprogram typo`?

Comment: That being the case, I'd start by writing a helper that calculates lexicographic distance between a given target (the typo'd command) and a list of possibilities in a real language so you can use that from bash.

Comment: You could use [bash completion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4793/74329) to avoid typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I don't know if this is how `git` does it exactly, but it would work). There is a concept called [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) which can be used to measure how close two strings are to each other. In this case, you would compute the edit distance between the input (`statsu`) and each of the possible matches (`status`, `commit`, `rebase`, etc), then suggest the one with that produced the smallest edit distance.

The Wagner-Fischer algorithm can be easily, although inefficiently, implemented recursively, but it should be fast enough for the short strings that would be compared for your use case.

```
# Warning: not tested, but should be close
# return (cost) is in variable wf_cost
wagner_fischer () {
    local t0 t1 t2
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        # Base case 1: first string is empty
        wf_cost=${#2}
    elif [[ -z $2 ]]; then
        # Base case 2: second string is empty
        wf_cost=${#1}
    elif [[ ${1:0:1} == ${2:0:1} ]]; then
        # Strings have identical first characters, recurse on the
        # rest of each string
        wagner_fischer "${1:1}" "${2:1}"
    else
        # Strings have differing first characters; recurse on
        # the rest of each string, but add 1 to the result to accommodate
        # the initial difference.
        #
        # Pick lowest cost of possible operations:
        wagner_fischer "${1:1}" "$2"     # deletion case
        t0=$wf_cost
        wagner_fischer "${1}" "${2:1}"   # insertion case
        t1=$wf_cost
        (( t0 < t1 )) && t1=$t0
        wagner_fischer "${1:1}" "${2:1}" # substitution case
        t2=$wf_cost
        (( t1 < t2 )) && t1=$t2
        (( wf_cost=t1 + 1))
    fi
}
```

To find the closest suggestion, you could use the above function like this:

```
min_cost=65535  # "Infinity"
for choice in status rebase commit; do
    wagner_fischer "$input" "$choice"
    if (( wf_cost < min_cost )); then
        min_cost=$wf_cost
        suggestion=$choice
    fi
done
echo "You typed $input, did you mean $suggestion?"
```

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if there are any algorithms that are weighted by the proximity of keys to each other on the keyboard...

Comment: Sure; the algorithm as shown in the linked wikipedia article assumes weights for each insertion, deletion, and substitution. In the above implementation, I just assume that all three have the same cost. Insertions and deletions, I think, would still cost the same, but the substitution cost would be relative the distance between the two letters. (Assigning such weights would be an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: oh hey @chepner!  you just edited my other bash question `:)`  this is the most likely solution to this problem.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I just re-read the edit you had made, and notice you are using a global variable to accumulate the distance, not using the exit status like my (deleted) comment assumed.

Comment: Yes, that's to avoid the multiple subshells (these spawn like crazy with a recursion like this). Did I actually break anything? I remember it seemed to work fine this way (and I remember it was unusable because of slowness with the subshells). Feel free to revert/fix if I did anything wrong!

Comment: No, it looks fine. I'm not too worried about the exact correctness, since I wouldn't actually recommend using it. I'd rewrite it as an iterative function, or implement it in a different language.